# Evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2 \left(-\frac{1}{1-z}\right)-\text{Li}_2 \left(-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)}{z}dz$

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form

I was trying to find a closed form for

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2 \left(-\frac{1}{1-z}\right)-\text{Li}_2 \left(-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)}{z}dz = -2.454199511\cdots$$

where $\text{Li}_2(z)$ is the [dilogarithm function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html). Numerically, it seems very close to $-\frac{49}{24}\zeta(3)$.

How can we prove that $-\frac{49}{24}\zeta(3)$ is the exact value of the integral?

Comment: if answer is got by numerically,nobody can proof analytically right?

Comment: look  how dilogarithm is defined by series http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrating by parts and using the known series results, we get that
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2 \left(-\frac{1}{1-z}\right)-\text{Li}_2 \left(-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)}{z}dz$$ 
$$=\int_0^1 \frac{\log (z+2) \log (z)}{z+1}dz+\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\log (2-z) \log (z)}{1-z} dz}_{\large \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k H_k}{k^2}=-5/8  \zeta (3)}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\log (1-z) \log (z)}{1-z}dz}_{\large\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n}{(n+1)^2}=\zeta (3)}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\log (z+1) \log (z)}{z+1} \, dz}_{\large \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n H_n}{(n+1)^2}=-1/8\zeta (3)}$$

For evaluation of the first integral, check my answer here [Proving that $\int_0^1 \frac{\log \left(\frac{1}{t}\right) \log (t+2)}{t+1} \, dt=\frac{13}{24} \zeta (3)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1344455/proving-that-int-01-frac-log-left-frac1t-right-log-t2t1-d).

Answer (score 13):

Let's use the [classical property of the polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Properties) $\ \displaystyle z\frac{\partial\operatorname{Li}_2(z)}{\partial z}=\frac {\operatorname{Li}_1(z)}z=-\frac{\ln(1-z)}z\,$ to rewrite this as a double integral :
\begin{align}
I&:=\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2 \left(-\frac{1}{1-z}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2 \left(-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)}{z}dz \\
&=\int_0^1 \frac 1z\left[-\int_0^{-1/(1-z)}\frac{\ln(1-t)}tdt +\int_0^{-1/(1+z)}\frac{\ln(1-t)}tdt\right]dz \\
&=\int_0^1 \frac 1z\int_{-1/(1-z)}^{-1/(1+z)}\frac{\ln(1-t)}tdt\,dz \\
\end{align}
Substitute $\,t:=t(y)=-\dfrac 1{1-y\,z}\,$ and use $\,\dfrac {dt}t=\dfrac {z\,dy}{1-y\,z}$ to get :
\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^1 \frac 1z\int_{1}^{-1}\ln\left(1+\frac 1{1-y\,z}\right)\frac z{1-y\,z}dy\,dz \\
&=-\int_0^1 \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(2-y\,z\right)-\ln\left(1-y\,z\right)}{1-y\,z}dy\,dz \\
&=\int_0^1 \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(1-y\,z\right)}{1-y\,z}dy\,dz -\int_0^1 \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(2-y\,z\right)}{1-y\,z}dy\,dz\\
&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1-y\,z\right)}{1-y\,z}dy\,dz+\int_0^1 \int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1+y\,z\right)}{1+y\,z}dy\,dz\\
&\quad -\int_0^1 \int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(2-y\,z\right)}{1-y\,z}dy\,dz-\int_0^1 \int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(2+y\,z\right)}{1+y\,z}dy\,dz\\
\end{align}

Such integrals were studied by Beukers and more generally by Guillera and Sondow in ["Double integrals and infinite products for some classical constants via analytic continuations of Lerch's transcendent"](http://arXiv.org/abs/math/0506319v3) and these four last integrals return fractions of $\zeta(3)$. More exactly :
$$I=-\zeta(3)+\frac 18\zeta(3)-\frac 58\zeta(3)-\frac {13}{24}\zeta(3)=-\frac{49}{24}\zeta(3)$$
with the correct result (a proof for the first and third integral is in the paper : see the examples $3.26$ and $3.25$).

**UPDATE (partial)**
The idea is to evaluate integrals like $\;\displaystyle\int_0^1 \int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(a-y\,z\right)}{1\pm y\,z}dy\,$ by expanding the logarithm as power series so that we will need to evaluate integrals like $\displaystyle \int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{(xy)^u}{1\pm xy} dy$.

Let's rewrite a little the [Lerch transcendent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function#Integral_representations) (see $(9)$ from the paper) :
\begin{align}
\Phi(z,s,u)&:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{(n+u)^s}\\
&=\frac 1{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-ut}\,t^{s-1}}{1-e^{-t}\,z}\,dt,\quad\text{setting}\;\;t:=-\ln(X)\;\text{gives}\\
&=\frac 1{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^1\frac{X^{\,u-1}\,}{1-Xz}(-\ln(X))^{s-1}\,dX\\
\end{align}
Setting $X:=x\,y\;$ we have $\,x=\frac Xy$ and $\,0\le X\le y\le 1\,$ getting (cf $(29)$) :
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^u\,y^v}{1-xyz}(-\ln(xy))^s dy\;dx&=\int_0^1\int_X^1\frac{X^u\,y^{v-u}}{1-Xz}(-\ln(X))^s \frac 1y\,dy\;dX\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{X^u}{1-Xz}(-\ln(X))^s\int_X^1 y^{v-u-1}\,dy\;dX\\
&=\frac 1{v-u}\int_0^1\frac{X^u-X^v}{1-Xz}(-\ln(X))^s\,dX\\
&=-\Gamma(s+1)\frac {\Phi(z,1+s,1+u)-\Phi(z,1+s,1+v)}{u-v}\\
\end{align}
For $z=1$ and at the limit $s\to 0$ (using the [series for digamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Recurrence_formula_and_characterization)) this becomes (cf $(40)$ and $(42)$) :
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^u\,y^v}{1-xy} dy\;dx&=\frac {\psi(1+u)-\psi(1+v)}{u-v}\quad\text{while for}\;\;v\to u\\
\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{(xy)^u}{1-xy} dy\;dx&=\psi'(1+u)
\end{align}
While for $z=-1\,$ and setting $\;\displaystyle \eta(x):=\psi(x)-\psi\left(\frac{x+1}2\right)\;$ I obtained :
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^u\,y^v}{1+xy} dy\;dx&=\frac {\eta(1+u)-\eta(1+v)}{u-v}\quad\text{and for}\;\;v\to u\\
\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{(xy)^u}{1+xy} dy\;dx&=\eta'(1+u)
\end{align}

The theorem $3.2$ from the paper should allow to conclude using $\psi(n+1)-\psi(1)=H_n$ (and $\psi'(n+1)=\dfrac{\pi^2}6$) as well as the corresponding formulae for $z=-1$ but I'll have to stop again...

---

An alternative method could be to use integration by parts :
\begin{align}
I&:=\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2 \left(-\frac{1}{1-z}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2 \left(-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)}{z}dz \\
&=\left.\ln(z)\left(\operatorname{Li}_2 \left(-\frac{1}{1-z}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2 \left(-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)\right)\right|_0^1-\\&\quad\int_0^1\ln(z)\left[\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac 1{1-z}\right)}{z-1}-\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac 1{1+z}\right)}{z+1}\right]dz\\
&=\int_0^1\ln(z)\left[\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac 1{1-z}\right)}{1-z}+\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac 1{1+z}\right)}{1+z}\right]dz\\
\end{align}
Again this gives four integrals (more or less easy to evaluate...)

Comment: Thank you Raymond, that's very helpful.

Comment: Glad you liked it @IntegralsandSeries. Of course a more direct derivation would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Wolframalpha can anti-differentiate your integrand. There are probably branch cuts involved which would make computing the integral more complicated than just plugging numbers into (or taking limits of) the anti-derivative.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to compute the integral analytically. The result is quite complex and I have not been able to simplify it. What I obtained is

-Log[3]^3 / 3 + Log[3] PolyLog[2, 1/9] / 2 -  Log[27] PolyLog[2, 1/3] + PolyLog[3, -1/3] -
 2 PolyLog[3, 1/3] +  Zeta[3] / 8

I hope and wish that there is no mistake.

Generating the first 10,000 digits, the number is identical to - 49 Zeta[3] / 24 but I cannot prove it is true.

Comment: Did you copy that expression from Mathematica?

Comment: No ! I computed all of that by hand !!! Yes, I used Mma for a big part of it. It would be good to simplify this last formula. I am surpized that no CAS (I used several) was able to simplify. Please let me know if anything new comes. Cheers.