# Evaluate $\int\limits_0^{\ln{2}}\ln(1+e^x)\ln(1-e^x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Wolfram [says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5Bln%5C%2840%29Power%5Be%2Cx%5D-1%5C%2841%29ln%5C%2840%29Power%5Be%2Cx%5D%2B1%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Cln2%7D%5D) it is approximately $-0.65111415588...$ but I am hoping for an exact solution. Here is my attempt:

$$\int\limits_0^{\ln{2}}\ln\left(e^{x}+1\right)\ln\left(e^{x}-1\right)dx$$
$$\int\limits_0^{\ln{2}}\ln\left(u\right)\ln\left(e^{x}-1\right)\frac{du}{e^x}$$
$$\int\limits_2^3 e^{-x}\ln\left(u\right)\ln\left(u-2\right)du$$
$$\int\limits_2^3 e^{-\ln\left(u-1\right)}\ln\left(u\right)\ln\left(u-2\right)du$$
$$\int\limits_2^3 e^{-\ln\left(u-1\right)}\ln\left(u\right)\ln\left(u-2\right)du$$
$$\int\limits_2^3 \frac{\ln\left(u\right)\ln\left(u-2\right)}{u-1}du$$

This is where I got stuck. I am thinking a series expansion might help but I am not sure.

Comment: I wrote "exact solution" instead of "closed form solution" because I do not expect it to have a closed form. I was hoping there might be a representation using special functions.

Comment: I have no reason to think it has an exact solution. I just came up with a problem as a challenge for myself and couldn't solve it, so I posted it here.

Comment: Integrals of this form can essentially always be given in terms of polylogarithm functions. The theory of multiple zeta values trivialises such logarithmic integrals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitute $t=e^x-1$
$$\int\limits_0^{\ln{2}}\ln\left(e^{x}+1\right)\ln\left(e^{x}-1\right)dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(t+2)\ln t}{t+1}\ dt= -\frac{13}{24}\zeta(3)$$
where the last step utilizes the [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1344455/686284).